# remove from the list of missing values None

Tags: python, list

```
[['user_1',
  'user_2',
  'user_8',
   None,
   None],
 ['ben',
  'karl',
   None,
   None]]
```

I try to remove the missing values

```
for element in df:
     element=[x for x in element if x is not None]
```

this code leave everything as it was

Comment: You could use [**`filter`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter), although that would also remove empty strings, zeroes, etc.

Comment: You may find this article helpful: [Facts and myths about Python names and values](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html), which was written by SO veteran Ned Batchelder.. And here's a condensed version of the same info, with cute diagrams: [Other languages have "variables", Python has "names"](http://python.net/~goodger/projects/pycon/2007/idiomatic/handout.html#other-languages-have-variables)

Comment: FWIW, none of the answers in that dupe target show how to mutate the existing list (or its sublists) rather than replacing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is that the line

```
element=[x for x in element if x is not None]
```

creates the new filtered list and binds it to the name `element`, which *replaces* the old list object that the name `element` was bound to. But we can use slice assignment to make it mutate that list instead:

```
df = [
    [
        'user_1',
        'user_2',
        'user_8',
        None,
        None,
    ],
    [
        'ben',
        'karl',
        None,
        None,
    ]
]

# Remove the `None` values
for element in df:
     element[:] = [x for x in element if x is not None]

for row in df:
    print(row)
```

**output**

```
['user_1', 'user_2', 'user_8']
['ben', 'karl']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
my_list= [['user_1',
  'user_2',
  'user_8',
   None,
   None],
 ['ben',
  'karl',
   None,
   None]]

print [ [ elt for elt in a_list if elt is not None ] for a_list in my_list ]
```

> [['user_1', 'user_2', 'user_8'], ['ben', 'karl']]

Comment: This would also remove list items with `0` in them...

Comment: @l'L'l right, fixed.

Comment: This is fine if `len(my_list)` is small, but if it's huge it's probably desirable to save RAM by mutating the existing list rather than replacing it. OTOH, replacing `my_list` _is_ a little faster than mutating it.

Answer (score 1):

```
for element in df:
     element[:]=[x for x in element if x is not None]
```

out:

```
[['user_1', 'user_2', 'user_8'], ['ben', 'karl']]
```

[Document](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types):
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Reassigning `element` does not alter the list, because `element` is a separate variable.

With a small change, you can generate a new outer list using a nested comprehension, something like this:

```
df = [[x for x in element if x is not None] for element in df]
```